# can somebody help me on how to fix the following error? "DATABASE QUERY ERROR-YOU PROBABLY FOUND A BUG"

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

Database Query Error - You've Probably Found a Bug
Database query failed
Please give all the information on this page to your support personnel.

```
Query select count(*) as rowcount from biblio left join biblio_copy on biblio.bibid=biblio_copy.bibid left join biblio_field on biblio_field.bibid=biblio.bibid and biblio_field.tag='700' and (biblio_field.subfield_cd='a' or biblio_field.subfield_cd='b') where (`biblio`.`author` like '%l\'eglige%' or `biblio`.`responsibility_stmt` like '%l\'eglige%' or `biblio_field`.`field_data` like '%l\'eglige%' )and opac_flg = 'Y' failed. The DBMS said this:

Table '.\openbiblio\biblio_copy' is marked as crashed and should be repaired
Debug Backtrace (most recent call first):
E:\xampp\htdocs\lasource\classes\Error.php:100 FatalHandler->printBackTrace()
E:\xampp\htdocs\lasource\classes\Error.php:68 FatalHandler->dbError('select count(*) as rowcount from biblio left join biblio_copy on biblio.bibid=biblio_copy.bibid left join biblio_field on biblio_field.bibid=biblio.bibid and biblio_field.tag=\'700\' and (biblio_field.subfield_cd=\'a\' or biblio_field.subfield_cd=\'b\') where (`biblio`.`author` like \'%l\\\'eglige%\'  or `biblio`.`responsibility_stmt` like \'%l\\\'eglige%\'  or `biblio_field`.`field_data` like \'%l\\\'eglige%\' )and opac_flg = \'Y\' ', 'Database query failed', 'Table \'.\\openbiblio\\biblio_copy\' is marked as crashed and should be repaired')
E:\xampp\htdocs\lasource\classes\Query.php:91 Fatal->dbError('select count(*) as rowcount from biblio left join biblio_copy on biblio.bibid=biblio_copy.bibid left join biblio_field on biblio_field.bibid=biblio.bibid and biblio_field.tag=\'700\' and (biblio_field.subfield_cd=\'a\' or biblio_field.subfield_cd=\'b\') where (`biblio`.`author` like \'%l\\\'eglige%\'  or `biblio`.`responsibility_stmt` like \'%l\\\'eglige%\'  or `biblio_field`.`field_data` like \'%l\\\'eglige%\' )and opac_flg = \'Y\' ', 'Database query failed', 'Table \'.\\openbiblio\\biblio_copy\' is marked as crashed and should be repaired')
E:\xampp\htdocs\lasource\classes\Query.php:286 Query->_act('select count(*) as rowcount from biblio left join biblio_copy on biblio.bibid=biblio_copy.bibid left join biblio_field on biblio_field.bibid=biblio.bibid and biblio_field.tag=\'700\' and (biblio_field.subfield_cd=\'a\' or biblio_field.subfield_cd=\'b\') where (`biblio`.`author` like \'%l\\\'eglige%\'  or `biblio`.`responsibility_stmt` like \'%l\\\'eglige%\'  or `biblio_field`.`field_data` like \'%l\\\'eglige%\' )and opac_flg = \'Y\' ')
E:\xampp\htdocs\lasource\classes\BiblioSearchQuery.php:118 Query->_query('select count(*) as rowcount from biblio left join biblio_copy on biblio.bibid=biblio_copy.bibid left join biblio_field on biblio_field.bibid=biblio.bibid and biblio_field.tag=\'700\' and (biblio_field.subfield_cd=\'a\' or biblio_field.subfield_cd=\'b\') where (`biblio`.`author` like \'%l\\\'eglige%\'  or `biblio`.`responsibility_stmt` like \'%l\\\'eglige%\'  or `biblio_field`.`field_data` like \'%l\\\'eglige%\' )and opac_flg = \'Y\' ', 'Error counting bibliography search results.')
E:\xampp\htdocs\lasource\shared\biblio_search.php:131 BiblioSearchQuery->search('3', array (
  0 => 'l\'eglige',
), 1, 'author', true)
```

Comment: Where is query ?

Comment: *Table '.\openbiblio\biblio_copy' is marked as crashed and should be repaired* is the only line you must consider. The table is damaged. You must repair it. Howto depends on the engine of this table.

Answer (score 1):

Your DB table crashed by some reason. You can repair it by next command:

```
mysqlcheck -uroot -p --repair db_name [tbl_name ...]
```

See [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqlcheck.html) for more options.

Answer (score 0):

As it said in error, you have broken myisam table biblio_copy in your database.

You need to run

```
 myisamchk -r /var/lib/mysql/openbiblio/biblio_copy.MYI
```

and restart mysql.

See additional info in [this post](https://ma.ttias.be/mysql-error-table-is-marked-as-crashed-and-should-be-repaired/)

Comment: Why you decide the engine of problematic table is MyISAM?

Comment: it is not me who created this DB. and the person who did this is nomore reachable